# How do I get these jQM 1.4 values out of a form with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile

I've got some settings I want to take out of a jQuery mobile 1.4 form to store in localStorage as the user settings for an app.

This is the form.

```
<form style="margin:0;padding:0;width:">                    
        <b>Age</b><br>        
        <input type="range" data-mini="true" data-highlight="true" name="ageview" id="ageview" min="0" max="99" value="30" >
        <p>                                                      
        <b>Gender</b><br>        
        <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="genderview" id="genderview" checked="" data-on-text="f" data-off-text="m" data-wrapper-class="custom-label-flipswitch" data-mini="true">                   
        <p>
        <b>Units<br><br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="unit_choice" id="unit_choice" value="metric_units" data-mini="true" checked="true">&nbsp;cm / kg
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="unit_choice" id="unit_choice" value="imp_units" data-mini="true">&nbsp;inches / ibs
        </label>
    </form>
```

As you can see, the 3 items in question (Age, Gender and Units) are held in different types of input. I'm trying to get them into variable like this:

```
$("#settings_close").click(function(){
//get settings
var age_set = $("#ageview").val();
var gender_set = $("#genderview").val();
var units_set = $("#unit_choice").val();
alert("Age is "+age_set+". Gender is "+gender_set+". Units are "+unit_choice);
});
```

and I'm using the console to check them and get this output, regardless of what the Gender checkbox is set to.

```
Age is 30. Gender is on. Units are [object HTMLCollection]
```

I've been experimenting with the val() and text() methods but I can't really get anything meaningful apart from the Age, which works fine. I must confess that I don't really understand what the "name" property in the inputs is for.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should never have two elements on your page with the same `id`.

That said in order to get the value from your radio buttons you can instead try using the name attribute

For example

```
$('input[name=unit_choice]:checked').val()
```

For your checkbox (flipswitch) you will want to check to see if the value is checked, one way to do that is to see if the checked selector matches anything.

For example

```
var gender = $('#genderview:checked').length > 0 ? 'f' : 'm';
```

Alternatively you can check the checeked property directly like [@ezanker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098622/ezanker) mentioned

```
var gender = $("#genderview").prop("checked") ? "female" : "male";
```

To update the vales you would do something similar, except that in addition you need to tell JQM to update the markup by calling the appropriate refresh method.

For example

```
  $("#genderview").prop("checked", gender == 'f').flipswitch('refresh');
```

Update to the fiddle [@ezanker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098622/ezanker) provided

http://jsfiddle.net/N7jxY/2/

Comment: Yeah, I realise I shouldn't have two elements with the same id. I've changed it. I've also tried your suggestion and I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: unit_choice is not defined" in the console.

Comment: Not sure what you might have done, but I'll try and add a fiddle in a few minutes.

Comment: My mistake. I had a small syntax error. I'm using     input:radio[name=unit_choice]:checked and that at least is getting me a value, but it's always the same value, metric_units, no matter which box is selected :(

Comment: Okay, got it working. I put value="metric" and value="imp" in the inputs. I just need to get the Gender thing working now.

Comment: For gender use var gender_set = $("#genderview").prop("checked") ? "female" : "male"; Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/N7jxY/

Comment: @ezanker I suppose your method of checking the gender is probably clearer.

Comment: Thanks Jack, that works. At last! Why is it so hard to check whether it's checked or not in jQuery!?

Comment: To be fair that doesn't really have anything to do with jQuery, When you do `$('#genderview').val()` you are just checking the value of the genderview element which doesn't change whether it is checked or not, what you want is to assign a value based on it's checked state. If you were doing it in vanilla JavaScript you would need to do something similar, for example `var gender = document.getElementById('genderview').checked ? 'f' : 'm';`.

Comment: So with this I get them both working, for reading. But once I've got the values and I store them I need to re-apply the the next time the user opens the application. They are stored in localStorage, which is fine, but the only one I'm able to re-insert into the form is the age, like this: $("#ageview").val(age_set); The others... I can't work out how.

Comment: When setting the vales you also need to tell JQM to refresh the markup http://jsfiddle.net/N7jxY/2/