# Getting values (settings) out of and back into a jQuery Mobile 1.4 form. How to do?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile

So this is the question I know I should have asked initially, here: 
[How do I get these jQM 1.4 values out of a form with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459358/how-do-i-get-these-jqm-1-4-values-out-of-a-form-with-jquery)

My issue is this - I have a settings panel that allows the user to choose age, gender and metric or imperial units. I store the settings in localStorage and whenever the user re-opens the application I want to pull them out of localStorage in order to implement them in the application.

This is the form

```
<form style="margin:0;padding:0;width:">                   
  <b>Age</b><br>        
  <input type="range" data-mini="true" data-highlight="true" name="ageview" id="ageview" min="0" max="99" value="30" >
  <p>                                                      
    <b>Gender</b><br>        
    <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="genderview" id="genderview" checked="" data-on-text="f" data-off-text="m" data-wrapper-class="custom-label-flipswitch" data-mini="true">                   
  <p>
    <b>Units</b><br>            
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">        
    <input type="radio" name="unitsview" id="metric_units" value="metric" checked="">
    <label for="metric_units">cm &amp; kg</label>
    <input type="radio" name="unitsview" id="imp_units" value="imp">
    <label for="imp_units">inches &amp; lbs</label>          
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

When the user clicks the save button, with id="newsettings" this script runs

```
$("#newsettings").click(function(){
    age_set = $("#ageview").val();
    gender_set = $("#genderview:checked").length > 0 ? 'f' : 'm';
    units_set = $("input[name=unitsview]:checked").val();
    settingsObject = { "ageset" : age_set, "genderset" : gender_set, "unitset" : units_set} //put settings in an object
    localStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(settingsObject)); //store string in localSettings}
);
```

Thanks to Jack in the other thread for that.

The problem is I don't know how to put these changes BACK into the form. The only one I can get working is the Age, like this

```
$("#ageview").val(age_set);
```

I've tried both

```
$("input[name=unitsview]").val(units_set);
```

and

```
$("input[name=unitsview]:checked").val(units_set);
```

and neither does anything.

And I don't know where to start with the Gender.

I'm not asking for just the solution using my form set up. The slider input clearly works for the Age though. My question is twofold:

1. Is there a way to easily insert the saved values? and
2. If not, is there some other way I can capture these settings in the form? Are there other controls that are easier to manipulate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback guys. I've been trying to reference my option in the select I'm using, like this.

```
$("#ageview").val(age);
if(gender == "f"){
    $("#genderview option[value='f_gender']").prop("selected", true).flipswitch( "refresh");
    $("#genderview option[value='m_gender']").flipswitch( "refresh");
} else{             
    $("#genderview option[value='m_gender']").prop("selected", true).flipswitch( "refresh");
    $("#genderview option[value='f_gender']").flipswitch( "refresh");
}   
if (units == "metric"){
    $("#metric_units").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio( "refresh" );
    $("#imp_units").checkboxradio( "refresh" );
} else {            
    $("#imp_units").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio( "refresh" );
    $("#metric_units").checkboxradio( "refresh" );
}
```

I just don't know how to reference these things in jQuery Mobile and the official docs confuse me :(

EDIT: And for an edit, here it is. This was so frustratingly easy.

```
$("#genderview").val(gender).flipswitch("refresh");
```

That's it.

2 days of struggle. :(

But I couldn't have done it without you guys. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/N7jxY/1/)**

```
$("#setVals").on("click", function(){
    var age = 32,
        gender = 'male',
        units = 'imp_units';

    $("#ageview").val(age);
    $("#genderview").prop("checked", gender == 'female').flipswitch( "refresh" );
    if (units == 'metric_units'){
        $("#unit_choice1").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio( "refresh" );
        $("#unit_choice2").checkboxradio( "refresh" );
    } else {            
        $("#unit_choice2").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio( "refresh" );
        $("#unit_choice1").checkboxradio( "refresh" );
    }
});
```

On the flipswitch you set the checked property to true or false and then call refresh on the widget.  For the radio buttons, you set the checked property for the appropriate one and then call the widget refresh on both.

Answer (score 1):

@ezanker's answer is correct in case values are stored in variables. However, when you use *localStorage* to save data and retrieve them later on, you cant use that method.

You need to save all data into an *array*, convert *array* into *JSON string* using `JSON.stringfy(array)` to be able to store it in *localStorage*.

To retrieve store data, *JSON string* should be *parsed* as *JSON array* in order to read values stored, using `JSON.parse(localStorage)`.

1. **Step one**:

   Loop through *form* elements, retrieve their *type*, *value* and *id*. Push each property into an *array*. Identifying *type* is a crucial step, based on it, element's *value* is retrieved. Moreover, *type* will be used in *switch statement* to update the *form*.

   ```
   var elements = []; /* array of data */

   $("#form_ID input").each(function () {

       /* type is either [type] or [data-role] */
       var elm_type = !! $(this).jqmData("role") ? $(this).jqmData("role") : $(this).prop("type");

       /* value is "string" or "boolean" */
       var elm_val = $(this).prop("type") === "checkbox" || $(this).prop("type") === "radio" ? $(this).prop("checked") : $(this).val();

       /* value will updated based on element's ID */
       var elm_id = "#" + $(this).prop("id");

       /* push data into elements array */
       elements.push({
           "type": elm_type,
               "value": elm_val,
               "id": elm_id
       });
   });
   /* array to string and save it */
   localStorage["info"] = JSON.stringify(elements);
   ```
2. **Step two**:

   To read data stored in *localStorage*, it needs to be *parsed* first. Then loop through values and update *form* using *switch statement*.

   Why *switch statement*? Each widget in jQuery Mobile has it's own *enhancement/update* method. i.e. updating a value of a checkbox/radio button, `.checkboxradio("refresh")` should be used to re-apply styles on that element.

   Note that I have used `.ui-page-active` selector to target elements by their *id* in active page. This is a *preventive measure* as not to target elements in any other page. You can use same *id* but on two conditions; 1) don't use them on the same page. 2) use *page's id* selector to target them.

   ```
   /* string to array */
   var load_info = JSON.parse(localStorage["info"]);

   $.each(load_info, function (i, data) {
       switch (data.type) {
         case "number": /* slider */
             $(".ui-page-active").find(data.id).val(data.value).slider("refresh");
             break;
         case "flipswitch": /* flipswitch */
             $(".ui-page-active").find(data.id).prop("checked", data.value).flipswitch("refresh");
             break;
         case "radio": /* radio button */
             $(".ui-page-active").find(data.id).prop("checked", data.value).checkboxradio("refresh");
             break;
       }
   });
   ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3JBgH/)** <sup>(1)</sup>

<sup>(1)</sup> Do changes on form -> Save -> Next Page -> Load -> Voilà!

Comment: good answer! I assumed from the question that the OP already had the localStorage part figured out and just did not know how to set the flipswitch and radio button...

Comment: Yeah, ezanker, I do have the localStorage part figured out fine. I use JSON.stringify and parse already. There is no problem with that and I can console.log all the values before and after stringifying them and parsing them fine. The Age variable is fine, and you are correct - if twas just knowing how to set the flipswitch and radio button that I don't get. I'm using a select for the flipswitch since it's easier to get the value from it.

Comment: @subjectiveeffect in case you have different form elements than the ones addressed in my answer, all you need is to add more _cases_ and of course retrieve their type and value.

Comment: @Omar I've actually used ezanker's version, because it fits with the rest of my code (I've already got a function that stores and retrives the localStorage into and out of JSON) and it works for the units. But I changed my flipswitch into a select with two options and it's just the referencing back I don't get. I can get the value of the option, I just can't put it back, yet.

Comment: Actually, I thought I had it working. Seems I don't know how to reference elements in forms.

Comment: @subjectiveeffect try my solution. Check the demo. All you need to bind click event to two buttons to save and load.

Comment: @Omar I know your solution works. But it's a little too complicated for me because I have to do other stuff with this data and I'd have to come back to Stack Overflow again and again. I just need to know how put the save gender setting into the gender flipswitch. I can't see how you have done that.

Comment: @subjectiveeffect flipswitch returns Boolean value, true or false as it's a checkbox. True means male, false means female. To set value `$("#id").prop("checked", true or false").flipswitch("refresh")`.